# Swift 2 storing dictionary permenently

Tags: swift2, nsuserdefaults

I'm trying to store a dictionary permanently on a `tableView`.

```
var places = [Dictionary< String,String >()];
```

Here is the code I have in viewDidLoad:

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(places, forKey: "diction");
places = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("diction") as! ([Dictionary< String,String >]);
```

Comment: You don't have anything in places. Your declaring [Dictionary< String,String >()]; will end up having an empty dictionary in an array. Clarify on what are you trying to save

Comment: I'm appending names. It's obviously not empty because the names appear on the cell. It's just that it's not stored permanently, so when I close and start the app the names go away.

Comment: because you save all your data in one `key` - `diction`. So, the value of your `diction` everytime will be the last `places`. That's why you loose your data on every relaunch

Comment: @AnitejRao: So your problem is that you save a populated dictionary to `NSUserDefaults` and you can't retrieve it. Are you sure? Can you show us what test have you done?

Comment: I run the simulator, stop the simulator and run it again and see nothing being stored in the table view. I'm assuming that's a conclusive test